# GSON get string from complex json

Tags: java, json, jsp, jakarta-ee, gson

I am trying to parse the JSON from this link: https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/items/56 , everything fine until i met the line: `"infix_upgrade":{"attributes":[{"attribute":"Power","modifier":4},{"attribute":"Precision","modifier":3}]}` ...

If i dont get this wrong: `infix_upgrade`has 1 element `attributes` inside him. `attributes` has 2 elements with 2 other inside them. Is this a 2 dimension array?

I have tried (code too long to post):

```
JsonObject _detailsObject = _rootObject.get("details").getAsJsonObject();
JsonObject infix_upgradeObject = _detailsObject.get("infix_upgrade").getAsJsonObject();
JsonElement _infix_upgrade_attributesElement = infix_upgradeObject.get("attributes");
JsonArray _infix_upgrade_attributesJsonArray = _infix_upgrade_attributesElement.getAsJsonArray();
```

The problem is that I dont know what to do next, also tried to continue transforming JsonArray into string array like this:

```
Type _listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
List<String> _details_infusion_slotsStringArray = new Gson().fromJson(_infix_upgrade_attributesJsonArray, _listType);
```

but im getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected STRING but was BEGIN_OBJECT` which i guess comes from the attributes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a proper formatting ([JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/), for example, checks if the JSON data is valid and does the formatting, which makes the structure more clear than what the GW link gives), `attributes` looks actually like this:

```
"attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute": "Power",
                    "modifier": 4
                },
                {
                    "attribute": "Precision",
                    "modifier": 3
                }
            ]
```

So it's an array of JsonObject and each object as two key-value pairs. This is why the parser throws an error because you require that this array contains only String which is not the case.

So the actual type is:

```
Type _listType = new TypeToken<List<JsonObject>>(){}.getType();
```

---

> The problem is that I dont know what to do next

Hold on. You are using Gson and Java is an OO language so I suggest you to create classes.

This would be easier for you to fetch the datas afterward and for the parsing since you just need to provide the class of the actual class the JSON data represents to the parser (some edge-cases could be handled by writing a custom serializer/deserializer).

The data is also better typed than this bunch of JsonObject/JsonArray/etc.

This will give you a good starting point:

```
class Equipment {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    ...
    @SerializedName("game_types")
    private List<String> gameTypes;
    ...
    private Details details;
    ...
}
class Details {
    ...
    @SerializedName("infix_upgrade")
    private InfixUpgrade infixUpgrade;
    ...
}
class InfixUpgrade {
    private List<Attribute> attributes; 
    ...
}
class Attribute {
    private String attribute;
    private int modifier;
    ...
}
```

and then just give the type to the parser:

```
Equipment equipment = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Equipment.class);
```

Hope it helps! :)